How can I get all sub-matches from pattern with syntax {n,m}
I want to use regular expression to match hotkey strings, such as ctrl+9, ctrl+alt+F10, etc.
So I designed this pattern to match:
^(([[:alpha:]]+)\\s*(\\+)\\s*){0,2}([[:alnum:]]+)$

I tested string ctrl+alt+F4, and the match do success. However, when I was trying to get the sub-match string ctrl, I found I couldn't. Here is my code.

std::string str = "ctrl+alt+F4";

std::regex pattern("^(([[:alpha:]]+)\\s*(\\+)\\s*){0,2}([[:alnum:]]+)$", regex::icase);

for (sregex_iterator iter(str.begin(), str.end(), pattern), end_iter; iter != end_iter; ++iter)
{
    int size = (*iter).size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << (*iter)[i] << endl;
    }
}


I only got ouput of ctrl+alt+F4, alt+, alt, + and F4.

Related to how-to-capture-multiple-repeated-groups, " If your capture group gets repeated by the pattern, only the last value that matches it gets stored."

So, split string by '+' seems simpler and would do what you want.

Yes, splitting solves this problem, but when the sub-pattern repeat a few more times  it is not operable.

There is still the lexer/parser way (which should also be overkill).

The usual solution is to do this in two steps. First use a regexp to extract the entire sequence. Then search for the individual matches in this result.

You cannot with that syntax.  You can if you change the <e>{m,n} into
(<e>)(<e>)(<e>)(<e>)(<e>)(<e>)?(<e>)?(<e>)?(<e>)?
[      (m)-entries      ][   (n-m)-entries      ]

so you will have m groups and you will have from m to n filled with data.  In your case
(([[:alpha:]]+)\\s*(\\+)\\s*)?(([[:alpha:]]+)\\s*(\\+)\\s*)?(([[:alpha:]]+)\\s*(\\+)\\s*)?([[:alnum:]]+)$

As you have three left parens in each group, you will have to check groups 1, 4 and 7 for data
